# When I enter a number in the input, the first function starts

Tags: javascript, html

I’m setting up a new server, and want to support UTF-8 fully in my web application.When I enter a number in the input, the first function starts!
First if the loop checks to see if a letter is entered at the input,if i enter the letter of the printout the array is defined.
If I enter the number "1" array is printed backwards!
Problem: if i enter number 1 in the input the first and second loops are executed and I only want function 2 to execute.

```
arrayfunction = () => {

  var numbers = [1, 2, 5, 7, 14];
  var text = document.getElementById('text').value;

  if (text.toLowerCase() && text.toUpperCase()) {
    console.log(numbers);

  }
  if (text === "1") {
    console.log(numbers.reverse()); //function 2
  }
  if (text === "2") {
    console.log(numbers.splice(1, 3)) // function 3
  }
  if (text === "0") { //function 4
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      numbers[i] = numbers[i] * 2;
    }
    console.log(numbers);
  }

}
```

```
<input type="text" id='text' onchange="arrayfunction(this.value)">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if it isn't a number, you need to use the isNaN() method. It checks if it is Not A Number. So your code can be changed to this:

```js
arrayfunction = () => {

  var numbers = [1, 2, 5, 7, 14];
  var text = document.getElementById('text').value;

  if (isNaN(text)) {
    console.log(numbers);

  }
  if (text === "1") {
    console.log(numbers.reverse()); //function 2
  }
  if (text === "2") {
    console.log(numbers.splice(1, 3)) // function 3
  }
  if (text === "0") { //function 4
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      numbers[i] = numbers[i] * 2;
    }
    console.log(numbers);
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" onchange="arrayfunction(this.value)">
```